# How can I print all children of a specific array that I detect via URL parameter?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, parameters

This is my array:

```
array(1) {
  ["farm"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["animals"]=>
    array(1) {
      [horses]=>
      array(4) {
        ["fred"]=>
        string(4) "fred"
        ["sam"]=>
        string(4) "sam"
        ["alan"]=>
        string(4) "alan"
        ["john"]=>
        string(4) "john"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my URL

```
mypage.php?id=2&dir=animals
```

I would like to print the children of my URL parameter `dir`(In this case:animals)

This is the way I try to do it:

```
 foreach($array as $sub) {
        if ($_GET['dir'] == $sub){
        $result = array_merge($result, $sub);
        echo $result;
        }
}
```

My result: An empty page.

The result I wish: `horses`

Comment: I found out that I need to write  `foreach($array as $sub => $key) {` but then my result is `farm`

Comment: If you want to use key it's the other way. `foreach($array as $key => $sub) {...}`

Comment: @Jarla, What will be the result if the `dir` is `animals`??

Comment: @FrayneKonok If `dir` is `animals`, the result should be `horses`

Comment: @FrayneKonok If `dir` is `horses` the result should be `fred sam alan john`

Comment: okey, wait for result

Comment: @Jarla, Your answer is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your array:**

```
$arr = array("farm" => 
             array("animals"=>
                   array("horses" => 
                         array("fred" => "fred",
                               "sam" => "sam",
                               "alan" => "alan",
                               "john" => "john")
                        )
                  )
            );
```

Here we go, i make a recursive function for searching the value.

> This function not work if you search for `fred` and their siblings.

```
$search = 'horses';
get_values($arr);

function get_values($arr){  
    global $search;
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if($key == $search){
            if(is_array($value)){
                echo join(", ", array_keys($value));
            }           
            else{
                echo $value;
            }
        }else{
            get_values($value);
        }       
    }   
}
```

**Output:**

> fred, sam, alan, john

Comment: One question, if I want to write instead of `fred, sam, alan, john` `<li>fred</li><li>sam</li><li>alan<l/i><li>john</li>`. How do I do that?

Comment: I do not know if this is the best way: `if(is_array($value)){
            echo "<li>";
                echo join("</li><li>",array_keys($value));
                echo "</li>";    
            }`

Comment: I get some problems when I want to make a link:   `if(is_array($value)){
            echo "<a href='mypage.php?id=".$id."&dir=".value."'><li>";
                echo join("</li></a><a href='mypage.php?id=".$id."&dir=".value."'><li>",array_keys($value));
                echo "</li></a>";    
            }`  the value in the link is always printing the word `Array` instead of the for example `fred`. And do I have to write the links twice?

Comment: Let's see tomorrow. Now I am sleeping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108384/discussion-between-jarla-and-frayne-konok).

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem is that I need as a result the same value inside the link of each like `<li><a href="mypage.php?dir=fred">fred</a></li><li><a href="mypage.php?dir=sam">sam</a></li>` I cannot get the second fred between it. But you helped me already enough, so I will make a new question for it :)

Comment: This is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448776/how-can-i-create-a-recursive-function

Answer (score 0):

Your `$array` has a `farm` key and that `farm` only contains your `dir` animals.

If everything is in `farm` you can do like this:

```
if(!empty($_GET['dir'])) {
  $result = array_merge($result, $array['form'][$_GET['dir']]
}
print_r($result);
```

I don't know what $result contains initially, but you can adapt if this is not the case or just `echo $array['form'][$_GET['dir']]` if you don't have multiple items in `$result`

Comment: what to do if the `dir` is `horses`.

Comment: @Frayne Konok yes it is possible, that `dir` is `horses`, also that `dir` is `farm`

Comment: From question is not clear if `dir` can be anything or just keys from `farm`. The solution from above is just for `farm` items. It needs to be adapted to check everywhere.

Comment: @DanielDudas `dir` can be anything

Comment: I tried to use your code, but I get an empty white page