# PHP - How can I create a recursive function?

Tags: php, arrays

My array:

```
array(1) {
  ["farm"] => array(1) {
    ["animals"] => array(1) {
      [horses] => array(4) {
        ["fred"] => string(4) "fred"
        ["sam"] => string(4) "sam"
        ["alan"] => string(4) "alan"
        ["john"] => string(4) "john"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My function (created by @FrayneKonok)

```
$id = "2";
$search = "horses";
get_values($arr);
function get_values($arr, $id) {
  global $search;
  foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($key == $search) {
      if(is_array($value)) {
          echo(join("<a href='mypage.php?id=".$id."&dir=".$value."'><li>",array_keys($value)));
          echo("</li></a>");    
      } else {
        echo($value);
      }
    } else {
      get_values($value);
    }
  }
}
get_values($array,$id);
```

The result is:

```
"fred"
<a href="mypage.php?id=2&dir=Array"><li>sam</li></a>
<a href="mypage.php?id=2&dir=Array"><li>alan</li></a>
<a href="mypage.php?id=2&dir=Array"><li>john</li></a>
```

The result I'm looking for:

```
<a href="mypage.php?id=2&dir=fred"><li>fred</li></a>
<a href="mypage.php?id=2&dir=sam"><li>sam</li></a>
<a href="mypage.php?id=2&dir=alan"><li>alan</li></a>
<a href="mypage.php?id=2&dir=john"><li>john</li></a>
```

Another example is when i use `if($search = "farm")` my result becomes:

```
"animals"
```

When the result I'm looking for is:

```
<a href="mypage.php?id=2&dir=animals"><li>animals</li></a>
```

Comment: let me double check again.

Comment: is your `id` is a fixed thing???

Comment: @Jarla some of your lines had quite a bit of unnecessary white-space. With large files excessive white-space this has the possibility to stump performance. Also In the line `["sam"] => string(4) "sam"` the length of "sam" is not 3 its 4 be careful, this could lead to errors.

Comment: i did it, You can test it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Online link](https://3v4l.org/sPBlk)

**Array and input, function call**

```
$arr = array("farm" => 
             array("animals"=>
                   array("horses" => 
                         array("fred" => "fred",
                               "sam" => "sam",
                               "alan" => "alan",
                               "john" => "john")
                        )
                  )
            );


$search = 'farm';
get_values($arr);
```

**Function:**

```
function get_values($arr){  
    global $search;
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if($key == $search){
            if(is_array($value)){
                $keys = array_keys($value);
                if(count($keys) > 1){
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++){
                        echo '<a href="mypage.php?id=2&dir='.$keys[$i].'"><li>'.$keys[$i].'</li></a>';
                    }
                }else{
                    echo '<a href="mypage.php?id=2&dir='.$keys[0].'"><li>'.$keys[0].'</li></a>';
                }
            }           
            else{
                echo $value;
            }
        }else{
            get_values($value);
        }       
    }   
}
```

**Output**

```
<a href="mypage.php?id=2&dir=animals"><li>animals</li></a>
```

Also tested for the `horses`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using another `foreach`

Instead of

```
if(is_array($value)){
    echo join("<a href='mypage.php?id=".$id."&dir=".$value."'><li>",array_keys($value));
    echo "</li></a>";    
}
```

Use

```
if(is_array($value)){
    foreach( $value as $k => $v ) {
        echo "<a href='mypage.php?id=".$id."&dir=".$k."'><li>".$k."</li></a>\n";
    }   
}
```

Also don't forget to pass `$id` each time

The whole thing becomes:

```
$arr = array( "farm"=> array(  "animals"=> array( "horses"=> array( "fred" => "fred", "sam" => "sam", "alan" => "alan", "john" => "john" ) ) ) );

$id = "2";
 $search = "horses";
    get_values($arr, $id); // <-- pass $id here

    function get_values($arr, $id){  
        global $search;
        foreach($arr as $key => $value){
            if($key == $search){
                if(is_array($value)){
                    foreach( $value as $k => $v ) {
                        echo "<a href='mypage.php?id=".$id."&dir=".$k."'><li>".$k."</li></a>\n";
                    }   
                }           
                else{
                    echo $value;  
                }
            }else{
                get_values($value, $id ); // <-- pass $id here to 
            }      
        }      
    }
```